# kendo for Angular 6 reuse DropDownList with different ngModel property

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to reuse code for multiple kendo DropDownList for Angular 6

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
    [data]="listItems"
    textField="text"
    valueField="value"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

by using *ngFor="let item of items" template.

```
let items = [[ngModel1, ngModel2, ngModel3]]
```

Is there a way which I could use to bing ngModel with miltiple instances from my items array?

Is anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to have three separate DropDownLists?  Or do you want to concatenate ngModel1, ngModel2, and ngModel3?

Comment: separate ngModel1, ngModel2, and ngModel3. Reuse same Html <kendo-dropdownlist></kendo-dropdownlist> but instead of copy paste 3 times almost same Html code, use template or something to reuse code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **let-dataItem** directive.

To define the item template, nest an  tag with the kendoTemplate directive inside the component tag. Then template context is set to the current component. 
To get a reference to the current data item, use the **let-dataItem** directive.

So dataItem's selectedItem will be storing model values.

Help API: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ItemTemplateDirective/

```
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem" let-formGroup="formGroup">
    <kendo-dropdownlist 
       [data]="listItems" 
       textField="text" 
       name="text" 
       valueField="value"
      [(ngModel)]="dataItem.selectedItem">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
  </ng-template>
```